# Please confirm my use of primary key and unique index

Tags: mysql, indexing, database-design, null, key

I think I understand primary keys and indexes.

In my setup, I have a table with several columns. Two of these columns are User ID, and Username.
Ideally I would like both to be unique, and non nullable.

As far as I can tell, my best use would be to have the User ID as the primary key, as this is the most important field not to NULL, and it will never change as the database grows.

I would then have to have the username column as a unique index, so that it can be the same on another row, although unfortunately, could end up NULL.

This is what I will do unless there is a way to have both columns as unique and non NULLABLE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From both my application development and datawarehouse experience I would recommend having a separate primary key that is not used in any business setting and do not use User ID as the primary key.  Using UserID as the primary key can lead to a whole host of problems.  I would index each column (separately).

Anytime you need to merge or reassign a user or change their ID, etc, having actually used their userID as the primary key will lead to a lot of problems for those operations.

Also, on the web, this will open up people seeing URL's like `....user/1/details` and then potentially being able to change the '1' to a '2' (for example) and seeing other peoples info.  It is better if the ID is unique like '57489574389ghfjghfjghf' and then it's harder to hack URLs with.

The choice between a 'natural' and a 'surrogate' key is explained well here:
http://www.agiledata.org/essays/keys.html

Most of the problems people experience in this area are for edge cases such as merges and deletes.  These are usually of low priority initially but concern over them will grow over time and poorly engineered solutions will start to break down (usually because at the point that data quality is 'recognized' there is often such a large volume of 'bad' data that going forward is untenable - the old data can't be 'fixed' and without that rules are hard to introduce for new records which will co-exist with them. This assumes that the ability to update old records is still required.

Comment: Thanks Michael, very thorough answer. I have the luxury of only creating an intranet, with very few users actually using the login ability. Security is second to functionality at the moment, though this may change in the future, as there is currently no sensitive data secured in this way, only user preferences.

Comment: @Eds: I DISAGREE... "It is better if the ID is unique like '57489574389ghfjghfjghf'" is a terrible suggestion.  This is like saying your IDs should always be a GUID.


Users being able to scrape the site using .../user/2/details is poor application design and bug. Should not be overcompensated by poor database design.

Answer (score 4):

You can declare the Username column as NOT NULL and put an unique index on it. Although the index itself won't force not-null values, the field definition will, so it will be effectively a unique non-nullable field.

Answer (score 0):

Nop, sorry to say you are incorrect, on both accounts.

1) Right about everything, except that the PK can change if you want it to.

2) Unique index is, by definition, unique, it cannot be repeated. What you mean is a plain old index, not unique, which can be repeated. Its purpose is to speed up querying if you filter often by that field. Otherwise is better not to use it.

What you want: Column1 = Primary Key (not null), Column2 = Unique Index (not null), exactly what you said, but now you know why it does work as you need it to.

EDIT: Also, it seems you make a corelation between indexes and non-nullables. You can make a column non-nullable, independently of whether it is an index or not.

Answer (score 0):

Totally agree with Michael, your primary key column should not contain any meaningful data, especially like userID. So you should add another column for the PK and fill it from a sequence.

Also agree with Darhazer: you should put a not null constraint and a unique index on both the userid and username fields.