# MYSQL - What is a primary key?

Tags: mysql, primary-key, specifications

I'm in the process of learning Mysql, and I'm creating databases. So, after looking at several websites, the definition for a primary key is:

The PRIMARY KEY constraint uniquely identifies each record in a database table.

and is used like this:

```
    CREATE TABLE Persons
(
    P_Id int NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (P_Id)          //primary key is on this line
)
```

However, I still don't  know what it's used for and why we need it. So my question is.

Can someone explain to me what a primary key is (in basic english) and why we need one and what is it used for?

Thank-you.

Comment: The only difficult part is... which other question is this a duplicate of?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between Primary Key, Unique Key and Index in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844899/whats-the-difference-between-primary-key-unique-key-and-index-in-mysql)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Key, Primary Key, Unique Key and Index in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844899/difference-between-key-primary-key-unique-key-and-index-in-mysql)

Answer (score 5):

A [primary key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_key) is a [column](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column_%28database%29) that is defined as *uniquely identifying* each row in a table.

Also, by defining a column as `PRIMARY KEY`, it may be referenced as a [*foreign key*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) in other tables when defining [referential integrity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity) constraints.

Comment: +1  You may also find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038641/please-confirm-my-use-of-primary-key-and-unique-index/8038647#8038647 useful.

Answer (score 3):

A primary key is a unique identifier for the row. It is normally automatically assigned by the  database management system (if you specify auto-increment for that value). So if you have a database of people in an organisation, their primary key may be their employee number. Every time you add an employee, they receive a unique employee number that is usually the previous employees number + 1.

Without primary keys you could not distinguish between two employees called John Smith (without other information) Hope that is clear enough.

Comment: I'd say 'sometimes assigned by the dbms' rather than 'normally', but otherwise agree.

Comment: Okay, fair call, I was being picky. Not meaning to start a fight.

Comment: @RichardA I would imagine "normal" is the norm these days (just as is not having a [real] DBA involved at any level...)

Answer (score 1):

In simple words,

**Primary Key = NOT NULL + UNIQUE**

that means whichever column is assigned primary key, that column will neither take NULL values nor accept the duplicate values.